# Unexpected token for "=>" and "object"

Tags: javascript

I got two **"unexpected token"** errors (in my editor) for this both lines, but they are working! What's the fail?

Error 1 (unexpected token "`>`")

```
var nameclean = name.replace(/\b(?:ä|ö|ü|ß)\b/gi, matched => umlauts[matched]);
```

Error 2 (unexpected token "`...style1,`")

```
var marker1 = L.circleMarker([000,000],{...style1}).addTo(map);
    markers.push(marker1);
```

Comment: If they're working, where exactly are you getting that "Unexpected token" error? In your editor? In the browser..?

Comment: Secondly, there's _nothing_ jQuery related in your question.

Comment: @AKX Yes, just in my editor and I can't minify this file (get also an error by the koala tool).

Comment: At the second part, yes, you are right, thats js - I have edited the headline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I got two "unexpected token" errors (in my editor) for this both lines, but they are working! What's the fail?

You're using a syntax checker which either doesn't support those JavaScript syntax features or is configured to check against an older version of JS.

Arrow functions and spread syntax were introduced in ES6. It looks like your checker is still on ES5.

Comment: Yes, that was also my "feeling" - so I just can ignore it, right?

Comment: You could, but updating your syntax checker would be a better idea. (On the other hand, there might be a reason for your checker to be configured that way, especially if you are maintaining an existing problem, such as a requirement for Internet Explorer support)

Comment: Yes, I will try. Have you a good (not online) alternative for minifying, like koala? Also thx for your explanations.

Comment: I use webpack for practically everything these days.

Comment: @Quentin You should look at https://vitejs.dev/ instead, in that case. It's truly a breath of fresh air, and that's coming from someone who's contributed to Webpack...